# RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in a course and try to find my problem. I can't understand why if I enter something other than 9 digits, the `if` should raise the `StopIteration` and then I want it to go to `except` and print it out. What is the problem?

```
def check_id_valid(id_number):
    if len(str(id_number)) != 9: raise StopIteration
    else:
        lst_id = list(map(int,str(id_number)))
        lst_id[1::2] = map(lambda x: x * 2, lst_id[1::2])
        lst_id = map(lambda x: (x % 10 + x // 10), lst_id)
        num1 = sum(lst_id)
        if num1 % 10 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def id_gen(id2):
    index = 0
    while index < 10:
        id2 += 1
        if check_id_valid(id2):
            index += 1
            yield id2

def main():
    try:
        gen_idnum = id_gen(int(input("Enter id number : ")))
        for n in gen_idnum:
            print(n)

    except StopIteration as e:
        print(e)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you raising `StopIteration` instead of something sane like `ValueError`? `StopIteration` serves [a very specific purpose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) (to allow a `__next__` method to indicate iteration is complete), and reusing it for other purposes will cause problems, as you can see. The conversion to `RuntimeError` here is saving you; if Python hadn't done that, the generator would have silently stopped iterating (`StopIteration` is swallowed silently, causing iteration to end without propagating the exception; you'd never catch it anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer since it apparently answered the OP's question:

**Don't raise `StopIteration`, raise something sane like `ValueError`.**

`StopIteration` serves [a very specific purpose](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) (to allow a `__next__` method to indicate iteration is complete), and reusing it for other purposes will cause problems, as you've seen. The conversion to `RuntimeError` here is saving you; if Python hadn't done that, the generator would have silently stopped iterating (`StopIteration` is swallowed silently, causing iteration to end without propagating the exception; you'd never catch it anyway).