# Why is a StopIteration exception raised by a generator not caught by try/except block?

Tags: python, generator

I have the following code:

```
def collatz_gen(n):
    if (n == 0):
        raise StopIteration("Cannot compute a Collatz chain starting at 0.")
    yield n
    
    while True:
        if (n%2 == 0):
            n = n//2
            yield n

        else:
            if n==1:
                raise StopIteration("Cannot generate past the first incident of 1 in the Collatz chain.")
            n = (3 * n + 1)
            yield n

def collatz_len(n):
    collatz = collatz_gen(n)
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            x = next(collatz)
            count += 1
        except StopIteration:
            return count
```

The problem is that catching the StopIteration does not work: the `collatz_len` method fails with a `RunTimeError` despite the `try/except StopIteration` block.

I know how to fix this: as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63155784/runtimeerror-generator-raised-stopiteration), changing the `StopIteration` exceptions to `ValueError` allows the code to complete as expected.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) has this to say:

> If a generator code directly or indirectly raises StopIteration, it is
> converted into a RuntimeError (retaining the StopIteration as the new
> exception’s cause).

I guess I'm trying to understand why this decision was taken: is it not natural to catch a `StopIteration` exception when your generator runs out of values? What's the upside of forcing it to be converted to the more general `RunTimeError`?

Comment: Generators are supposed to `return` when they are finished, not raise an exception. Raising an exception typically means something went wrong and cannot be computed the intended way. But when your generator should just finish generating, then this isn't an abnormal situation, it's part of the generation process. As for the why, if this `StopIteration` was leaked as is, it could stop outer generators; e.g. if you have `yield from other_gen(); yield 'final'` and `other_gen()` would leak a `StopIteration`, then this would stop the outer generator which clearly isn't the intention here.

Comment: Oh, so should i have `if(n==1) return` instead?

Comment: No, ignore sorry. that didn't work. I'll try again.

Comment: You can use `return 'my message'` which will appear as a `StopIteration` with `'my message'` as the argument on the outside.

Comment: @a_guest Until Python 3.7 (or when `from __future__ import generator_stop` was in effect), `raise StopIteration` was *a* way to terminate a generator. (Prior to Python 3.5, I think it was the *only* way; `return` statements weren't allowed in a generator function at all.) PEP-479 explains the rationale for changing the relationship between `return` and `raise StopIteration`.