# StopIteration in comprehension

Tags: python

If I put a deque comprehension in a 'try-except' structure, a StopIteration exception raised while creating the deque is not caught, but causes the code to crash. Why is that? Here's a minimal example; below is an application.

```py
>>> i = iter('aaa')
>>> deque( [ next(i) for _ in range(10) ], 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
StopIteration

>>> i = iter('aaa')
>>> deque( ( next(i) for _ in range(10)), 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
>>>
```

Here's some context. I'm writing a function to read n-grams off an iterator. The following works fine, even if the sequence is shorter than n:

```py
def ngrams( sequence, n=2):
  sequence = iter(sequence)
  # fill 'ngram' with the first ngram
  try:
    ngram = deque( [next(sequence) for _ in range(n)], maxlen=n)
  except StopIteration:
    return

  # for this and subsequent ngrams: yield, then advance
  while True:
    yield tuple(ngram)
    try:
      ngram.append(next(sequence))
    except StopIteration:
      return
```

If the sequence is shorter than n, the function yields nothing and terminates in an orderly fashion:

```py
list(ngrams('aaa',10))
[]
```

But I get a different behavior if I replace the list in the first 'try' block with a generator (leaving everything else unchanged):

```py
...
  try:
    ngram = deque( (next(sequence) for _ in range(n)), maxlen=n)
...
```

This time, if the sequence is too short, I get an error "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration". Why is this StopIteration not caught by my 'except' statement?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a _"deque comprehension"_; that's a list comprehension and a generator expression, the resulting list/iterator is just an argument to `deque`.

Comment: _"Why is this StopIteration not caught by my 'except' statement?"_ - because it's not a `StopIteration`, it's a `RuntimeError` _caused by_ a `StopIteration`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71114016/3001761.

Comment: I believe it's because one of the errors with using generators is a RuntimeError, which your try-except block doesn't catch because it's only looking for StopIterations

Comment: See also the Itertools Recipe [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @MarkTolonen You mean `sliding_window`.

Comment: @KellyBundy no I meant grouper, but I might misunderstand what ngram is. The OP’s examples aren’t clear.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Hmm, I'd say their function that "works fine" makes it clear.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I'm not sure I understand why StopIteration is sometimes leads to RuntimeError, but at least I know that this happens. Thanks also to @MarkTolonen, although it's true that sliding_window is what I had in mind.